# Undefined symbols with json spirit and Os X Mavericks

Tags: macos, osx-mavericks, json-spirit

Since the recent update Mavericks, I have a problem linking with the library json_spirit.

I installed the new Command Line Tools, but I'm using gcc47 installed via macports. Json spirit (v4.06) has been compiled with the same gcc (after the update).

```
gcc (MacPorts gcc47 4.7.3_3) 4.7.3
```

I boiled it down to the following example :

**test.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "json_spirit_reader_template.h"
#include "json_spirit_writer_template.h"
#include "json_spirit_writer.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    json_spirit::mValue a;
    std::string s("[]");
    json_spirit::read_string(s, a);
    std::cout << json_spirit::write_formatted(a) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which I compile with the following :

```
g++ -I/usr/local/include test.cpp -o test -L/usr/local/lib -ljson_spirit
```

And it gives this error :

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "json_spirit::write_formatted(json_spirit::Value_impl<json_spirit::Config_map<std::basic_strin    g<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > const&)", referenced from:
      _main in ccwUclng.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

And finally, using "nm -g /usr/local/lib/libjson_spirit.a | grep write_formatted" :

```
nm: no name list
0000000000000150 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEE
000000000003afa8 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEE.eh
0000000000000120 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIcS5_EE
000000000003af80 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIcS5_EE.eh
0000000000000270 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEE
000000000003b118 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEE.eh
0000000000000240 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIwS5_EE
000000000003b0c8 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_10Config_mapINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIwS5_EE.eh
0000000000000090 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEE
000000000003aeb0 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEE.eh
0000000000000060 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIcS5_EE
000000000003ae88 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIcNS2_11char_traitsIcEENS2_9allocatorIcEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIcS5_EE.eh
0000000000000210 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEE
000000000003b0a0 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEE.eh
00000000000001e0 T __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIwS5_EE
000000000003b078 S __ZN11json_spirit15write_formattedERKNS_10Value_implINS_13Config_vectorINSt3__112basic_stringIwNS2_11char_traitsIwEENS2_9allocatorIwEEEEEEEERNS2_13basic_ostreamIwS5_EE.eh
```

I don't know how to read the nm output, so I may be missing something obvious.

I've tried to install and uninstall every component (boost ..) one by one, compiling with the gcc from macports and / or the default, which is :

```
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.0 (clang-500.2.79) (based on LLVM 3.3svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.0
Thread model: posix
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is a half answer, because I never really got to explain exactly what happened, but I fixed it, so..

The answer was to rebuild boost from scratch, (icu as well) with the new system and the same compiler everywhere, for me it's gcc 4.7.3 installed with macports.

Also, I was trying to upgrade from boost 1.53 to boost 1.54, so it may have been part of the problem, but now anyway I went back to boost 1.53.